# Honda BR-V v 1.5L Manual 2016 (India)

Tags: electric-vehicle, instrument-cluster

Does the Oil Life indicator function works on Honda BR-V v 1.5L (India) .
If it works can you tell me the procedure how to bring Oil life indicator on its multi information display.

Comment: Have you searched for the workshop manual - that may have the information you need.

Comment: In multi information display there is option but I'm not getting the way to activate that function. And there is no information about it in workshop manual.

Comment: How to attach image in this comment section.I want to show you that oil life option to you.

Comment: So it may not be implemented for that model, perhaps no sensor or just not implemented even if there is a sensor.

Comment: You can attach an image to your question by using the "edit" button below the question text, and then selecting the "moon and mountains" icon in the header of the composition window.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

This is the image for above asked Q

below Trip A
Oil Life